# how to add currentmonth and year into an alias in access sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want this result

Partnumber_currentmonth -> for example like:

```
A1234_0317
```

How can I reach this?

Comment: You can only do this with dynamic sql

Comment: @HoneyBadger you can do it in plain sql in MS Access with Format

Comment: @Fionnuala can u tell me more? whats plain SQL?

Comment: An ordinary query, not dynamic. `SomeColumn & Format(SomeDate, "mmyy")` Use the query design window in MS Access.